# Why is my mixed voice raspy

Tags: voice

I am a Baritone, I have been singing with a vocal coach for about a year now and about 3 days ago I finally discovered my mixed voice (yay). It is incredibly weak but I can sometimes push it up to a High Tenor C.

My highest note in chest is A# on a good day with the wind behind me, but when I mix higher than this, often my tone is very raspy, and can flip into a fry-scream sound.

How can I improve my mixed voice to sound brighter and cleaner, without distortion? Is this just going to improve with time or am I doing something  fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Haha I know the feeling of finally finding the mixed voice. I think what you could do(besides asking your vocal coach for help of course), is to try doing arpeggios with "gug" first so that you develop the proper balance between chest and head. Once you get comfortable with that, then you can should joining the notes together to smoothen and strengthen your mix. At least this is what I did haha. If you need more singing tips/help with singing in general, check out my blog @ http://superiorsingingsuccess.weebly.com/home/how-to-sing-better-instantly-4-singing-tips